# Same MySql Query Long execution time but short on archive table with 6million more records

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, gps

I am a bit stumped on this wierdness.
I have a gps tracking app that logs gps points into a track_log table.
When I do a basic query on the running log table it takes about 50 seconds to complete:

```
 SELECT * FROM track_log WHERE node_id = '26' ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

When I run the exact same query on the archived table where I copied most of the logs to to reduce the running table's logs to about 1.2 million records.
The archive table is 7.5 million records big.

The exact same query on the archive table runs for 0.1 seconds on the same server even though it's six times bigger!
What's going on?

```
Here's the full Create Table schema:


    CREATE TABLE `track_log` (
    `id_track_log` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `node_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `client_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `time_stamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `latitude` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    `longitude` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    `altitude` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    `direction` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    `speed` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_code` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_description` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `street_address` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `mileage` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `run_time` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `satellites` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `gsm_signal_status` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
    `hor_pos_accuracy` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `positioning_status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `io_port_status` char(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    `AD1` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `AD2` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `AD3` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `battery_voltage` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ext_power_voltage` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `rfid` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pic_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `temp_sensor_no` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_track_log`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_track_log_UNIQUE` (`id_track_log`),
    KEY `client_id_fk_idx` (`client_id`),
    KEY `track_log_node_id_fk_idx` (`node_id`),
    KEY `track_log_event_code_fk_idx` (`event_code`),
    KEY `track_log_time_stamp_index` (`time_stamp`),
    CONSTRAINT `track_log_client_id` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES    `clients` (`client_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `track_log_event_code_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`event_code`) REFERENCES `event_codes` (`event_code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `track_log_node_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`node_id`) REFERENCES `nodes` (`id_nodes`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8632967 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Yes, 36 to 50 seconds on the 1.2million table... And 0.1 sec on the 7.5million archive table

Comment: Your UNIQUE key is redundant with the PRIMARY KEY.  DROP the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly because your archive table has superior indexing to your track_log table.

To satisfy this query efficiently you need a compound index on `(node_id, time_stamp)` Why does this work? Because InnoDB and MyISAM indexes are so-called BTREE indexes, which means our intuition about searching them in order will work. Your query looks for a specific value of `node_id`, which means it can jump to that value in the index efficiently. The query then calls for the highest possible value of `time_stamp` related to that `node_id` value. Now that's in the same index, and in the right order to access it quickly too. So the row you need can be random-accessed, and MySQL doesn't have to hunt for it by scanning the table row by row. That scanning is almost certainly what's taking the time in your query.

Three things to keep in mind:

One: lots of indexes on single columns can't help a query as much as well-chosen compound indexes.  Read this http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Two: `SELECT *` is usually harmful on a table with as many columns as the one you have shown.  Instead, you should enumerate the columns you actually need in your `SELECT` query. That way MySQL doesn't have to sling as much data.

Three: The `DOUBLE` datatype is overkill for commercial-grade GPS data. `FLOAT` is plenty of precision.

Comment: Hi Ollie, thank you for that, I have added a compound index on both the node_id and time_stamp coloumns and that solved the problem. The query runs now for 0.001 seconds

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

- Make sure the indexes are defined in both tables, for this query `node_id` and `time_stamp` are good indexes.
- Defragment your table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html (This could help, but should not make this much of a difference).
- Make sure your query is not being blocked by other queries. If data is being inserted in the `track_log` table at continuously, those queries might block your query. You can prevent this by changing the transaction isolation level, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html for more information. *Caution: be carefull with this!*

**Indexes**

I'm guessing this has something to do with the indexes you defined on the tables. Could you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLES track_log` output and the output of your archive table as well? The query you are executing would require an index on `node_id` and `time_stamp` for optimal performance.

**Defragmentation**

Besides this indexes you defined on the table, this might have something to do with data fragmentation. I'm assuming you are using InnoDB as your table engine now. Depending on your settings, every table in a database is stored in a separate file or every table in the database is stored in a single file (`innodb_file_per_table` variable). Those files will never shrink in size. If your `track_log` table has grown to 8.7 million records, on disk, it still takes up space for all those 8.7 million records.

If you have moved records from your `track_log` table to your archive table, the data might still be at the beginning and the end of the physical file for `track_log`. If no index is defined at `time_stamp`, a full table scan is still required to order by the timestamp. This means: reading the complete file from disk. Because the records you deleted still take up space in the file, this could make a difference.

*Edit:*

**Transactions**

Other transactions might be blocking your `SELECT` query. This can happen with the InnoDB engine. If you continously insert a lot of data into your `track_log` table, those queries might block your query. It will have to wait until no other transactions are being performed at this table.

There is a way around this, but you should be careful with this. You are able to change to transaction isolation level of your query. By setting the transaction isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED` you will be able to read data, while the other inserts are running. But it might not always give you the latest data. If you want to sacrifice this depends on your situation. If you are going to alter the data and update the data later, you generally do not want to change the transaction isolation level. But, for example, when showing statistics which should not always be accurate and up to date, this could be something that really speeds up your query.

I use this myself sometimes when I need to show statistics from large tables which are updated regularly.

Comment: Hi mdekker, thanks for your reply, I do have indexes for the time_stamp and node_id column. The only difference I do see is that the track_log table has 3 foreign key constraints defined with No action on Update or Delete (I didn't set it up, I am the second developer taking over for the front-end) They simply reference to smaller (10-30 records) tables. I'm thinking it could be these FK's?

Comment: I'm not sure if you work on a producation environment? You might want to try to defragment the table. If you are actually working on the production environment, this might block your table for any read/writes, depending on your MySQL version. Be sure you wish to do this on a production environment.

You should try changing the transaction isolation level first if you have a lot of other queries running on this table, especially queries which alter/insert data.

Answer (score 0):

Let us analyze your query:

```
SELECT * FROM track_log WHERE node_id = '26' ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

The above mentioned query first sorts all the data present in the table based on `time_stamp` and then returns the top row.

But, when this query is executed on `archived table`, `order by` clause might be ignored (based on compression and system setting) and hence it returns the first row it encountered in the table.

You may verify the output of archived table by comparing the result with actual latest row.